# Test boolean variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I created a series of tools, and I stumbled a series of issues with the processing workflow due to boolean variables.

I have the following example:

```
a = False
b = 'false'
c = 1

if a:
    print('a is: ', a)

if b:
    print('b is: ', b)

if c:
    print('c is: ', c)
```

Output:

```
b is:  false
c is:  1
```

Why in the above example I don't get my a value printed? I am using Python 3. Thanks!

Comment: Because a is False?

Comment: Uhh, I thought the condition is testing if a variable exists, even if the variable is False.

Comment: @Litwos Then you were mistaken.

Comment: @khelwood: In my program the variable can come either as 'false' or False, so I think that condition is not good to proper manage the workflow

Comment: @Litwos check my answer, hope this is what you needed.

Comment: @FalconUA: the variable always exists in the locals(), but the problem is that the value it gets is either 'false' or False. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question, it is simply because `a` is `False`.

---

However, I assume that what you wanted to do is to check the **existence** of `a`, `b`, and `c`, right?

To check the existence of a local variable:

```
if 'myVar' in locals():
# myVar exists.
```

To check the existence of a global variable:

```
if 'myVar' in globals():
# myVar exists.
```

---

In python, the types are fixed. You cannot cast one type to another like in Javascript. So in your code:

- `False` is just false. That's why it won't print out the stuff inside `if` statement.
- `'false'` is a string, but you can do `if` with it. Consider the following:

  ```
  if "":
       print("1")

  if "abc":
       print("2")
  ```

  this will print only `2`, so the `if` statement here is checking whether the string is not empty.
- Same thing with `if` used on integers. It will check whether the number is not zero.

Comment: I need to see if the variable is 'false' or False. So my condition is not proper.

Comment: Added some explanation to the Python syntax. If you have a variable that is either a string `"false"` or a boolean `False`, you can check `if a == "false" or a == False:`.

Comment: I think I understand now. The 'if <var>:' condition works differently depending on the value type (empty string is False, False is False, and 0 is False). Did I understand right?

Comment: Yes, it seems like that. And also, `None` is treated as `False`, too.

Comment: Aye. It's clear now. I gotta be more careful with if statements. :D

Answer (score 2):

Because your condition is : if a:
And a is false

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

```
if something:
   action
```

For `action` to be executed, `something` must be `True`. This is not the case of your `a`, so the `action` (printing) is not executed here.

So in your case, if you want to print that, you need to use `not`:

```
if not a:
    print('a is: ', a)
```